# Log4j RollingFileAppender has odd behavior when using the Log4j 1.x bridge

Tags: java, logging, log4j

While I migrate to log4j2, I have configured my Tomcat web application to use the
Log4j 1.x bridge. I followed the Migration guide here:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

I continue to use my existing log4j.properties file which look like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/mylog.out
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %t %c - %m%n
```

This successfully creates my log file and rolls over at 10KB.

I am having an issues that I can't explain. Here are the files in my log
directory:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 7.6K Jan 10 12:27 test.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root 11K Jan 10 12:27 test.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root root 36K Jan 10 12:27 test.log.2
-rw-r----- 1 root root 11K Jan 10 12:27 test.log2022-01-10
```

I get a log file named for the current day. I've experimented and it looks
like the RollingFileAppender is also rolling at the end of each day. It
didn't do this before using the bridge. Any idea why this is happening and
how to stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: This was a bug and was [fixed](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/710) in version 2.17.2.

This is a bug and you should report it. The `RollingFileAppenderBuilder` (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/c393e952b291a14fcb6a3140493bd4f69cd00413/log4j-1.2-api/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/builders/appender/RollingFileAppenderBuilder.java#L192)) has a `filePattern` containing a date instead of a number:

```java
        String filePattern = fileName +"%d{yyy-MM-dd}";
        TriggeringPolicy timePolicy = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.newBuilder().setModulate(true).build();
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy sizePolicy = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(maxSize);
        CompositeTriggeringPolicy policy = CompositeTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(sizePolicy, timePolicy);
        RolloverStrategy strategy = DefaultRolloverStrategy.newBuilder()
                .setConfig(config)
                .setMax(maxBackups)
                .build();
        return new AppenderWrapper(RollingFileAppender.newBuilder()
                .setName(name)
                .setConfiguration(config)
                .setLayout(fileLayout)
                .setFilter(fileFilter)
                .setBufferedIo(bufferedIo)
                .setImmediateFlush(immediateFlush)
                .setFileName(fileName)
                .setFilePattern(filePattern)
                .setPolicy(policy)
                .setStrategy(strategy)
                .build());
```

and hence it behaves more like the [`DailyRollingFileAppender`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/c393e952b291a14fcb6a3140493bd4f69cd00413/log4j-1.2-api/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/builders/appender/DailyRollingFileAppenderBuilder.java#L171), than a Log4j 1.x `RollingFileAppender`.

As a workaround you can use the older `Log4j1ConfigurationFactory` by setting these system properties:

```
log4j2.configurationFactory=org.apache.log4j.config.Log4j1ConfigurationFactory
log4j2.configurationFile=classpath:log4j.properties
```

Comment: Piotr created the PR https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/710 which has been merged for the next 2.x release.

Comment: Hi, this information is useful. In which version does it have the fix? We are using log4j 2.17.2 and still seeing a remarkably similar issue.

Comment: It was supposed to be a size based rolling but doesn't seem to be working as expected. May be time based. FYI, I tried adding the 2 system properties as well.

Comment: The OP's problem was fixed in 2.17.2.

Comment: We had similar problem in using the log4j bridge jars sometime back when the log4j vulnerability was reported. We cloned to code, and applied the fix and built in our local, and pushed the changes to our private artifactory and referred it in our project. which fixed the issue. but now it seems to be fixed and available.